# How do I Persist special characters (like ñ) to Cassandra with Spring Data Cassandra?

Tags: cassandra, spring-data, special-characters, datastax-java-driver, spring-data-cassandra

We have a usecase where we need to persist and retrieve special character strings into Cassandra. We're using Spring-Data-Cassandra for this. However while persisting Ñisson with Spring Data Cassandra, ?isson is getting persisted. The special character is getting replaced with ? in Cassandra.

I could persist it to Cassandra using CQLSH, so the DB Schema supports these special characters. But SpringBoot is not able to persist it.

I tried adding properties as:-

```
spring.datasource.connectionProperties=useUnicode=true;characterEncoding=utf-8;
```

But nothing seemed to work.

Is it possible to persist it as Ñisson into DB and retrieve it also with Ñisson as the PartitionKey using Spring Data Cassandra?

Comment: Can you file a ticket at https://jira.spring.io along a bit of code that demonstrates the issue? That sounds like a bug somewhere. Note that `spring.datasource` is related to JDBC and not Cassandra.